# Add No Result found tag when no results are present in textextjs script

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, tags, jquery-textext

I'm using [textextjs](http://textextjs.com/manual/examples/autocomplete-with-tags.html), This works pretty well and results are easily displayed when found in the list.
But when there is no data matching my present query, then my concern is to show "No results found" label in the drop-down itself.

This can be tackled by css show-hide "No result found" label. But this is doesn't behave as a drop-down.

Can someone suggest a better way to handle this?